# Can you run Linux on a Skylake processor?

Tags: linux, windows, cpu

I'm thinking of buying some new computers for my home (e.g. desktop workstations), but I read an article the other day suggesting that some processors from Intel were intentionally being manufactured in such a way that would only allow them to run Windows 10...

I personally do not like Windows 10 (too many privacy and confidentiality risks introduced with their EULA...and the future subscription model is not something I would subscribe to anyways) so I will likely load some variant of Linux...maybe Linux Mint?  (I have other servers running FreeBSD, but these will be workstation OS machines)

Anyways, what processors should I avoid if I want to run Linux instead of Windows?  I prefer to choose what operating system my hardware runs (vs. the manufacturer dictating to me), but if I have to choose, I definitely want Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Naturally. But are you perhaps also referring to the integrated GPU?

Comment: W7/8/10 can run on Skylake.

Answer (score 0):

If you were reading a post, such as [this](http://www.theverge.com/2016/1/16/10780876/microsoft-windows-support-policy-new-processors-skylake), then you have nothing to fear as those posts are letting people know that MS is trying to force people to use the latest version of Windows.  Even if a processor manufacturer were to make something that's "Windows Exclusive" the Linux kernel hackers would probably laugh and enjoy the challenge of trying to make the kernel run on that processor.  So long as the processor is using the standard x86 or better, the x86_64 architectures, then the Linux flavor of your choice should run just fine on it.  There has been a large number of, "Windows Only" hardware out there, such as the Xbox, but people have gotten [Linux to run on them](http://xboxlinuxproject.wikia.com/wiki/How_To_Install_Linux).

Edit:  While the link below doesn't pertain to processor hardware per se, it does prove my point a little bit.  There are plenty of people out there with the time and skills to break down whatever barriers corporations come up with, and the more popular it is, the faster it will get broken.
http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20021110

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run Linux on Skylake processors - I'm doing that now - that said, getting it running was not a pleasant experience as Linux needs to catch up with changes to the architecture - specifically getting my laptop to "not crash" was interesting, and required the latest version of Ubuntu, esoteric GRUB parameters, and it still produces (silently) scary looking logs in syslog - and can't run KVM (actually vnc I suspect) with graphics accelleration - and the system is very jerky without it.   If I were to do things over I'd have gotten a 5th gen rather then 6th gen processor.

There are some other things to be mindful of -

1. A lot of the small, cheap Intel tablet systems require a 32 bit bootloader but use a 64 bit OS (For example the Dell Venue 11).  This is supported on only some varients of Linux.
2. Chromebooks and some other devices have got locked bootloaders - these may not let you run Linux, or may require other hacks.  If you have a system with "Secureboot" running Windows, and you can't disable secureboot, you may have difficulty running Linux - this should not be a problem in x86 devices, but could be problem with ARM based CPU's.
3. Drivers - just because a system will boot does not mean it will work well - WAN drivers, touchscreen drivers and other bits may not be properly supported by the system.

In short, yes, Linux will work just fine on new systems, but you need to ensure it will work before you purchase it (and double Check - Dell told me my system would work with Linux.... except the person who told me this was clueless and did not realise it was a newer generation which Dell washed there hands of - I got it working anyway eventually)